# R: a faster way to export plots as .pngs with a lot of data?

Tags: r, performance, export, png

I am plotting a lot of data in R in a loop and export the plots to png in 300dpi resolution using `png()`. With all my data I am creating about 2000 plots in the end. This takes about 15 minutes to execute. When exporting to postscript using `postscript()` it takes about 20 seconds to process the whole data. The approximate file size for a resulting .png is about 300KB and for a .ps it is about 5KB

Is anyone aware of a faster png export method than this? Thank you for your suggestions.

```
# Plot NAME and ID as filename
for(i in 1:length(ind)){
  png(names(ind[i]), width=3358, height=2329, res=300)
  # if postscript; uncomment following line 
  # postscript(names(ind[i]))
  par(mar=c(6,8,6,5))
  plot(ind[[i]][,c('YEAR','VALUE')],
       type='b',
       main=ind[[i]][1,'NAME'],
       xlab="Time [Years]", 
       ylab="Value [mm]")

  dev.off() 
}
```

Comment: Other than getting a faster machine, or using the `parallel` package to divvy up the load, about your only choice wwould be to reduce the resolution.

Comment: reducing the resolution and getting a faster machine are clear 'solutions', just figured I'll ask if anyone might know about a faster export method using theses settings (resolution and dimension are predetermined) because I haven't found anything. Will have a look into the parallel package, thanks.

Comment: Postscript creates smaller files and is faster because it creates vector graphics instead of bitmap graphics.Looking at your code it's very likely that you *should* create vector graphics.

Comment: This is clear, but the plots will be used in a webpage application and therefore have to be in *.png format (not my decision...)

Comment: These images are over 3000 pixels by over 2000 pixels. Your screen is probably not much more than 1200 pixels. If these are going on the web, they are going to get squashed, your users will be downloading massive files for nothing, and it will be slow. Unless the web application is some kind of zooming, panning thing that will only show a window on the graphic, REDUCE THE PIXEL SIZE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a reproduicible example would be:

```
dir.create("DummyPlots")
setwd("DummyPlots")

system.time( for(i in 1:500)
  {  png(paste0("Image", i, ".png")) ; plot( i ) ; dev.off()  })
# 7.5 s
```

Here's a way that's a little faster:

```
system.time(  {png("FastImage%03d.png")
for(i in 1:500)
plot( i )
dev.off()  })
# 5.2 s

setwd("..")
unlink("DummyPlots", recursive=TRUE)
```

Comment: That's pointless: you just reduced the resolution to 72.  While I agree that 72dpi is more sensible, it's not what the OP presented.

Comment: You can still specify the resolution! The difference between the two code blocks is calling png 2000 times, or just once. I can image that for more complex/large images, you might even save more time...

Comment: I see yr point, and admit I assumed the major timewaster was generating each image.  Howsabout you run a time trial to see where the bottleneck is?

Comment: I ran the same code again, but with "width=3358, height=2329, res=300" and just a 100 times, and had 33 vs 28 seconds. So not really a relevant timesaver. As the comments to the OP show, image size will need to be reduced...